# Is there any common interface between ReadOnlySpan<T> and IReadOnlyList<T>?

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0

I wonder whether there is any interface, pattern or whatever when both `ReadOnlySpan<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` (and also more generic interfaces) are involved, **and you wish to avoid useless allocation**.

Consider this method using `IEnumerable<T>`, but don't mind the actual function:

```
    public byte Compute(IEnumerable<byte> buffer)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            byte lrc = 0;
            foreach (byte cell in buffer)
            {
                lrc ^= cell; //just an example
            }
            return lrc;
        }
    }
```

The calculation is made over a sequence of bytes (even sometimes I'd need an indexed/random-access stream). Thus, the sequence could be an array, a segment of that, or any enumerable source.

So far, I wasn't able to find a decent way to generalize the method signature (even accepting some overload as conversion), without actually allocating an array or something "heavy".

Is there anything yet, or even planned for the incoming .Net Standard 2.1?

Comment: Excellent question. I've been wondering the same thing. One often wants to support overloads for both `ReadOnlySpan<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` (or just `IEnumerable<T>`), yet maintain only a single implementation.

Comment: @Timo thanks for the "excellent"! it was a normal question, with a concrete problem behind. Still wonder why someone downvoted it without explaination.

Comment: I approached the problem by creating a `readonly ref struct` with a field for a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` and one for an `IReadOnlyList<T>`. Two constructors allow setting either one. The struct then allows enumeration over (or operation on) the one that is set, for example, indexed access through `T this[int index]`. Regrettably, it does need a branch on every access: `T this[int index] => this.Enumerable is null ? this.Span[index] : this.Enumerable[index]`. I've tried to take the branch out, such as by storing a `Func`, but it does not play well with span's `ref struct` nature: nothing's allowed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, this seems the least-ugly solution I've found:

```
    public byte Compute(IEnumerable<byte> buffer)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            byte lrc = 0;
            foreach (byte cell in buffer)
            {
                this.ComputeCore(ref lrc, cell);
            }
            return lrc;
        }
    }


    public byte Compute(ReadOnlySpan<byte> span)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            byte lrc = 0;
            foreach (byte cell in span)
            {
                this.ComputeCore(ref lrc, cell);
            }
            return lrc;
        }
    }

    private void ComputeCore(ref byte acc, byte cell)
    {
        acc ^= cell;
    }
```

Of course, it is worthwhile only when the core function become a bit complex than the one depicted.

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to use `for` over `ReadOnlySpan` instead of `foreach` since indexing is efficient with `Span`?

Comment: @NetMage I agree, but the problem is another.

Comment: @NetMage  using `foreach` with `Span`/`ReadOnlySpan` is just as efficient as a `for(int i =...)` loop - in an optimized build you should see identical machine code in both cases. See here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1085